# Echo different values from foreach loop (last array)

Tags: php, loops, foreach

i have a $_POST array from form submission.
My datas are:

```
Array (
[codice_fiscale] => CODICEFISCALE 
[sesso] => F 
[comune_nascita] => H501 
[anno_nascita] => 82 
[mese_nascita] => 03 
[giorno_nascita] => 13
 )
```

i need to print,foreach value, a string like the follow, in order to put it in a Ajax variables form:

```
codice_fiscale: CODICEFISCALE,
sesso: F,
comune_nascita: H501,
anno_nascita: 82,
mese_nascita: 03,
giorno_nascita 13
```

I've tried this

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){

   echo $key.' : "'.$value.'",</br>';}
```

but , of course, he puts the dot also at the last element.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the strings in an array and join them with `implode()`.

```
$array = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $array[] = "$key: $value";
}
echo implode(',<br>', $array);
```